# Chrome extenstion - Open new tab and insert data when DOM loaded

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, tabs

i want to ask about issue which i had while i want to create my own chrome extension. I want to create extension, for my blog to fill the article form automatically.

I want to count articles, and then ( due article count ) open tab, paste data, open tab, paste second data ...

I created manifest, background.js and content.js files.

After icon click i start background.js ( count articles, select data and paste to array - everything works good), but at the time, when i want to open new tab with url ( e.g. www.google.com ) and after DOM of tab is loaded, paste data to input and when the pasting is complete, i want to open new tab and repeat the action.

But, my issue is: "how to check when the tab DOM is loaded and when the script finish pushing data and call open new tab and repeat."

Any ideas how to solve this? Thanks a lot.

Btw sorry for my english... :-/

Comment: Why do you want to open a new tab with google? Please be more specific.

Comment: i need open form to add article on my blog administration and than paste article here. need paste 10 articles at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [chrome.tabs.onUpdated](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onUpdated).

chrome.tabs.onUpdated has a callback with parameter `changeInfo`. and `changeInfo` include status.

I think below code might works. (didn't run it)

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated(function(id, changeInfo) {
  if (changeInfo.status && changeInfo.status == "complete")
    // insert data
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer, but i created this simple script:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
   var action_url = "http://google.com";
   chrome.tabs.create({ url: action_url });
   run(tab.id);
});function run(tabId){
     chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, info, tab) {
     alert("new tab id is: " +tabId);

     if (info.status && info.status == "complete"){
         alert("complete");
         document.body.innerHTML = "";
     }
   });
}
```

But the ALERT is still runed early than dom of page is loaded, and the next java script code is not runed, because the dom isnt exist yet... this is still same problem.

P.S.: i used google as example, when u use some "bigger" site, u can see the alert run before whole page is loaded